# How to get the first deposits

Tags: mysql

I need to find the data of the first time an user made a deposit in a website, I have 2 tables:

**Table 1:** details on the user

id, user_id, user_name, registration_date, other_anagraphic_data

**Table 2:** details on deposit and actions

id, user_id, action_date, deposit_amount, items, actions

Now, an user can sign up in a date (data in table 1) and make a deposit in another date (even several weeks later), or an user can make more deposits in the same days or it can do some actions without to make a deposit. (data in table 2)

At the end of the month I would like to get a list of users (and relative data in table 1) who made their first deposit within the specified month.

Thanks for all the suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a query like this

```
SELECT MIN(B.action_date) as date_deposit, A.*
FROM user_details A
INNER JOIN user_deposits B ON (B.user_id = A.user_id)
WHERE B.deposits > 0
GROUP BY A.user_id
HAVING MONTH(date_deposit) = '05' AND YEAR(date_deposit) = '2014'
```

see this on [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f4b6d/5/0)

Comment: I tried your query but I get an error in the WHERE clause "invalid use of group function"

Comment: @user3708819 I corrected the query and I posted an example in sqlfiddle

Comment: Hi, yes I've had to modify the query a little but it works as the one proposed by spencer, I chose your because it is smaller and more versatile.

By the way both the answers took me in the correct direction, thanks to both of you!!!

P.S. To get the right result I've had to add  WHERE B.deposits > 0 before grouping

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to build a query to get the specified result.

Start with getting the "earliest" date each user made a "deposit". Assuming that `action_date` is either a MySQL DATE, DATETIME or TIMESTAMP datatype, or of another datatype that is canonical format,  such that "earlier" dates sort before "later" dates:

```
SELECT d.user_id
     , MIN(d.action_date) AS earliest_deposit_date
  FROM table_2 d
GROUP BY d.user_id
```

If there's other criteria that distinguishes a "deposit" from other actions, e.g. a non-negative and non-zero deposit amount, add that in a `WHERE` clause in that query, assuming `deposit_amount` is numeric, for example:

```
SELECT d.user_id
     , MIN(d.action_date) AS earliest_deposit_date
  FROM table_2 d
 WHERE d.deposit_amount > 0 
GROUP BY d.user_id
```

Next, check whether that "earliest_deposit_date" for each user is within the specified range, by referencing this query as an inline view. Assuming that `action_date` is a MySQL DATE, DATETIME or TIMESTAMP datatype, to check for earliest deposit date within April 2014:

```
SELECT e.user_id
     , e.earliest_deposit_date
  FROM ( SELECT d.user_id
              , MIN(d.action_date) AS earliest_deposit_date
           FROM table_2 d
          WHERE d.deposit_amount > 0 
          GROUP BY d.user_id 
       ) e
WHERE e.earliest_deposit_date >= '2014-04-01' 
  AND e.earliest_deposit_date <  '2014-04-01' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
ORDER BY e.user_id
```

To also retrieve values from the "user" table, add a JOIN operation. Assuming that `user_id` is a unique (or primary) key in the "user" table, and assuming `user_id` in table_2 "matches" user_id in the "user" table:

```
SELECT e.user_id
     , e.earliest_deposit_date
     , u.id
     , u.user_id
     , u.user_name
     , u.registration_date
  FROM ( SELECT d.user_id
              , MIN(d.action_date) AS earliest_deposit_date
           FROM table_2 d
          WHERE d.deposit_amount > 0 
          GROUP BY d.user_id 
       ) e
  JOIN table_1 u
    ON u.user_id = e.user_id
WHERE e.earliest_deposit_date >= '2014-04-01'
  AND e.earliest_deposit_date <  '2014-04-01' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
ORDER BY e.user_id
```

If any of the assumptions are wrong, the query will need to be adjusted accordingly.